# Moodle 3.5 self registration mail failed: auth_emailnoemail error

Tags: moodle

I am running moodle 3.5.3 LTS and I activate self registration.
When an user tries to create a an account, the following error happened:

```
Debug info: 
Error code: auth_emailnoemail
Stack trace:
line 482 of /lib/setuplib.php: moodle_exception thrown
line 142 of /auth/email/auth.php: call to print_error()
line 99 of /auth/email/auth.php: call to auth_plugin_email->user_signup_with_confirmation()
line 89 of /login/signup.php: call to auth_plugin_email->user_signup()
```

When I execute the following php script, the mail is sent without error:

```
<?php
 mail("me@mydomain.com","My subject","this is a test from php mail function");
```

I can send successfully mail from the command line using the mail command:

```
mail -s "Hello World" me@mydomain.com
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `noreplyaddress` configuration field fixes the issue.

NB: enabling `debugsmtp` setting can be helpful to debug emails issues.